# Why does Gmail force close when I open it?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, force-close

Every time I open my Gmail app it force closes. This is the message I get:

> The application Gmail( process com.android.gmail) has stopped
>   unexpectedly. Please try again.)

If it helps I am using the Samsung Galaxy S II running Android 2.3.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Settings>Applications>Manage Applications`, then find the Gmail app in the 'All' tab. Click 'Force Stop' and 'Clear Data'. Restart the app and see if the error occurs again.